# Openlayers 4 build not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, openlayers, openlayers-3, gwt-openlayers

I forked the official openlayers repo, and I followed the instructions from [here](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/DEVELOPING.md) to make  a local build, but i get the following error when i run 'make build':

`node tasks/build.js config/ol.json build/ol.js
info ol Parsing dependencies
ERR! SyntaxError: Unterminated string constant (10:2)
D:\openlayers\openlayers\src\ol\render\webgl\circlereplay\defaultshader.js:10
  'pre
  ^
make: *** [Makefile:243: build/ol.js] Error 1`

My environment consists in :

- Windows 8.1
- Cygwin 2.8.2
- GNU Make 4.2.1
- Python 2.7.13
- npm 3.10.10
- Java 1.8.0_131-b11